# How do I install a signed driver on Windows 10 without getting "Program Compatibility Assistant" message

Tags: code-signing, device-driver, windows-10-desktop

When I try to install my device driver, I get the

"Program Compatibility Dialog"
A digitally signed driver is required :  Process Detection Driver Cetrus.  Windows blocked the installation of a digitally unsigned driver.  Uninstall the program or device that uses the driver and check the publisher's website for a digitally signed version of the driver.

My driver is signed:

```
        Verifying: PDetect64.sys
        Signature Index: 0 (Primary Signature)
        Hash of file (sha1): 039DFBD6C922B86BC9D8E2ABF9AADAB800ABE21E

        Signing Certificate Chain:
            Issued to: AddTrust External CA Root
            Issued by: AddTrust External CA Root
            Expires:   Sat May 30 03:48:38 2020
            SHA1 hash: 02FAF3E291435468607857694DF5E45B68851868

                Issued to: COMODO RSA Certification Authority
                Issued by: AddTrust External CA Root
                Expires:   Sat May 30 03:48:38 2020
                SHA1 hash: F5AD0BCC1AD56CD150725B1C866C30AD92EF21B0

                    Issued to: COMODO RSA Code Signing CA
                    Issued by: COMODO RSA Certification Authority
                    Expires:   Mon May 08 16:59:59 2028
                    SHA1 hash: B69E752BBE88B4458200A7C0F4F5B3CCE6F35B47

                        Issued to: Cetrus LLC
                        Issued by: COMODO RSA Code Signing CA
                        Expires:   Sun May 26 16:59:59 2019
                        SHA1 hash: 647ACC3A5A36302E3A096F05595FD94EF8ED530D

        The signature is timestamped: Fri May 26 10:58:35 2017
        Timestamp Verified by:
            Issued to: UTN-USERFirst-Object
            Issued by: UTN-USERFirst-Object
            Expires:   Tue Jul 09 11:40:36 2019
            SHA1 hash: E12DFB4B41D7D9C32B30514BAC1D81D8385E2D46

                Issued to: COMODO SHA-1 Time Stamping Signer
                Issued by: UTN-USERFirst-Object
                Expires:   Tue Jul 09 11:40:36 2019
                SHA1 hash: 03A5B14663EB12023091B84A6D6A68BC871DE66B

        Cross Certificate Chain:
            Issued to: Microsoft Code Verification Root
            Issued by: Microsoft Code Verification Root
            Expires:   Sat Nov 01 06:54:03 2025
            SHA1 hash: 8FBE4D070EF8AB1BCCAF2A9D5CCAE7282A2C66B3

                Issued to: AddTrust External CA Root
                Issued by: Microsoft Code Verification Root
                Expires:   Tue Aug 15 13:36:30 2023
                SHA1 hash: A75AC657AA7A4CDFE5F9DE393E69EFCAB659D250

                    Issued to: COMODO RSA Certification Authority
                    Issued by: AddTrust External CA Root
                    Expires:   Sat May 30 03:48:38 2020
                    SHA1 hash: F5AD0BCC1AD56CD150725B1C866C30AD92EF21B0

                        Issued to: COMODO RSA Code Signing CA
                        Issued by: COMODO RSA Certification Authority
                        Expires:   Mon May 08 16:59:59 2028
                        SHA1 hash: B69E752BBE88B4458200A7C0F4F5B3CCE6F35B47

                            Issued to: Cetrus LLC
                            Issued by: COMODO RSA Code Signing CA
                            Expires:   Sun May 26 16:59:59 2019
                            SHA1 hash: 647ACC3A5A36302E3A096F05595FD94EF8ED530D


        Successfully verified: PDetect64.sys

        Number of files successfully Verified: 1
        Number of warnings: 0
        Number of errors: 0
```

Can somebody help with how to go about figuring out why Windows 10 thinks this is an unsigned driver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ***ONLY*** way is to sign the driver with an EV code signing certificate.

Answer (score 0):

What specific version of Windows 10 you are running?  Starting with new installations of Version 1607 of Windows 10, Windows not load any new kernel mode drivers which are not signed by the Dev Portal. For more details, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/kernel-mode-code-signing-policy--windows-vista-and-later-

Comment: Windows 1703.. and the kernal mode driver is a SOFTWARE only driver ... the Dev Portal ONLY handles hardware related device drivers

Comment: Please take a look at the instructions in this site https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/dashboard/get-started, regarding submitting software-only kernel mode drivers.  Hope this is helpful to you.

Comment: @user3174075 if this is helpful to you, please mark this post as Answered for others' benefits.